# How to edit table values in MySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have that people can add team names to my MySQL table. Now I want them to edit it. I have tried several tutorials but i can't figure it out. I like to know what i am doing wrong.

This is my admin.php:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);



        if(isset($_POST['team'])){
            $team = $_POST['team'];
            $ID = $_POST['id'];         

            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e2teams WHERE Team='$team' and ID='$ID'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ) { //check if there is already an entry for that username
                echo "$team bestaat al!";
            }
            else{
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO e2teams (Team) VALUES ('$team')");
                header("location:e2admin.php");
            }
    }

    mysql_close();
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Add teams</h1>
            <form action="e2admin.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="team" placeholder="Team naam" /><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Toevoegen" />
            </form>

            <?php
                $table = "e2teams";
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM e2teams";
                $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbhandle);
                if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                        echo $row['Team']. "<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[1]'>Bewerk</a><br>";
                    }
                }
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The add teams works. but the edit button doesn't work yet. If I click on edit I go to the edit.php page; here I want to add the new name and need the Team to change in the MySQL row.

This is my edit.php:

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost";

    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

    if( isset($_GET['edit'])) {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e2teams");
        $row= mysql_fetch_array($res);
    }

    if (isset ($_POST['nieuwenaam'])) {
        $newname = $_POST['nieuwenaam'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $sql = "UPDATE e2teams SET Team='$newname' WHERE id='$id'";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Fout bij updaten".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=edit.php'>";
    }
?>      


<html>
<body>       


            <form action="edit.php" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="nieuwenaam" placeholer="test" /><br>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" placeholder="idnaam" value"s" /><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also like to know how to delete team names but this is maybe for a next question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `doesn't work`? Are you receiving some kind of error message, or nothing happens? Please, share more details on your problem.

Comment: If you are struggling to find the cause of the problem because no errors are happening, stick a bunch of echos for variables in your code, to make sure everything is coming through as it should.

Comment: Your `placeholer` attribute is spelt wrongly, by the way.

Comment: Note that your code above is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Also the `mysql` extension has been depreciated; you should use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: I don't know how to use PDO or mysqli? is it easy to get this done in PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could not connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db("login", $dbhandle);

$id = intval($_GET['edit']);
if($id > 0) {
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM e2teams WHERE `id` = $id");
    $row= mysql_fetch_array($res);

    $newname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nieuwenaam']);
    if (!empty($newname)) {
        $sql = "UPDATE e2teams SET Team='$newname' WHERE id=$id";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Fout bij updaten".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=edit.php?edit=$id'>";
    }

}
?>


<form action="edit.php?edit=<?= $id; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="nieuwenaam" placeholer="test" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** Also, about the intval() and mysql_real_escape_string(). Since you were using $_GET without any filter, I've added intval() function on it. Without filtering $id you could've been easily attacked by some sort of e.g. SQL Injection. Same with mysql_real_escape_string(). You might read about this filter function in php manual. For further study I recommend changing mysql_ functions to PDO or mysqli prepared statements. Happy coding!

Comment: It might be worth explicitly mentioning in this sort of answer the steps you've taken to guard against SQL injection, especially since the OP is vulnerable. Good stuff though!

Comment: Hi thanks for your reaction. But if i do this it still doesn't work. I don't have an error but if i click on the update button the page refreshes to: _exemple_: edit.php?edit=0. But the name doesn't change

Comment: Well. This must be this line in the admin.php: 
`echo $row['Team']. "<a href='edit.php?edit=$row[1]'>Bewerk</a><br>";`

Be sure to change `$row[1]` to `$row['ID']`;

Comment: I can't change it to $row['ID'] i have a syntax error then this one: _Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysqllogin\admin\E2\e2admin.php on line 43_ **This is what i have now on admin.php:** echo $row['Team']. "<a href='edit.php?edit=$row['ID']>Bewerk</a>

Comment: Ah, yeah, syntax. `echo $row['Team']. '<a href="edit.php?edit='.$row['ID'].'">Bewerk</a><br>';` Also, read my note as I edited the post.

Comment: The edit function works now i can edit the team name! only i still get an error in edit.php: _Notice: Undefined index: nieuwenaam in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysqllogin\admin\E2\edit.php on line 15_ I don't understand this error because nieuwenaam is just the name of my fill in form

Comment: Its just a notice. Because your $_POST['nieuwenaam'] is initialized only when submiting POST.  You can use `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` in the beggining of the edit.php file after `<?php` to hide it. Also, check the answer as the correct to help the others also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your edit form. You have to put the value attribute like this value="s" no like value"". I think thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when they click on the edit link it's passing the id of the *team* so the edit.php `select` should be something like:

```
$id = (int)$_GET['edit'];
if (!empty($id))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM e2teams WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
}
//... keep the rest of code as is
```

Now you need to change the HTML form to:

```
<form action="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="nieuwenaam" placeholer="test" value="<?php echo $row['Team'] ?>" /><br>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" placeholder="idnaam" value"<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" /><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi i used your code. But when i come in the edit.php; the **_value="<?php echo $row['Team'] ?>" />_** always shows the first name in my table not the name i clicked on. also when i click on Update this error shows up: **_Notice: Undefined index: edit in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysqllogin\admin\E2\edit.php on line 10_** and also this error shows up underneath: **_Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysqllogin\admin\E2\edit.php on line 40_**
" />_

Comment: Base on the error it means you are not passing the id the team through query string. `var_dump` your `$_GET` and see what index name did you use for that or make sure on the `<a href="edit.php?edit=<?php echo $row[1]">something</a>` has a value